# Сортировка в компоненте catalog.section.list

Tags: php, битрикс, компоненты, фильтрация, фильтр

Есть тип инфоблока Каталог и инфоблок Товары, в котором располагаются разделы Компьютеры и ноутбуки, Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио, Товары для дома, Товары для кухни. Внутри раздела Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио располагаются подразделы Аудиотехника, Кронштейны и крипежи, Спутниковое ТВ, Телевизоры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код для вывода разделов второго уровня

```html
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list",
    "catalog",
    Array(
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => $arParams["ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS_FILTER" => "CNT_ACTIVE",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "sectionsFilter",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
        "SECTION_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
        "TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
        "VIEW_MODE" => "TILE"
    ),
    $component
);?>
```

Но в результате на странице отображаются разделы 2-ого уровня, упорядоченные по алфавиту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться вывода разделов по возрастанию ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в параметры

```
"CUSTOM_SECTION_SORT" => ["ID" => "ASC"]
```

Доступно с версии модуля iblock 20.0.400

Comment: а можете привести ссылку на эти параметры (откуда вы черпали информацию), а также соответствующие параметры компонента в интерфейсе битрикс?

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3796

Comment: там на странице наведите курсор на "сортировку данных в компоненте" чтобы увидеть параметры компонента в интерфейсе битрикс

Comment: там на странице написано, что: "В случае использования отдельного компонента catalog.section.list или news.list необходимо четко понимать, что редактировать сортировку данных в компоненте через визуальный редактор будет нельзя", но при этом приведен скриншот визуального редактора, в котором можно задать сортировку. Так все таки в визуальном редакторе можно задать сортировку для catalog.section.list?

Comment: Не получилось. Параметры "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "ID", "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "ASC" не помогли

Comment: Изменил свой ответ)

Comment: помогло. А почему первый вариант с заданием параметров ELEMENT не помог?

Comment: Скорее всего этот компонет не принимает такие параметры.

Comment: Можно еще вручную задать в поле Сортировка каждого раздела цифры, в каком порядке нужно выводить.